# PowerShell DateTime Conversion

Tags: powershell, date

I have this script which I have working for log files containing entries with a date format of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. However, I'm at a loss how to read log entries formatted with `yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss` as the date format.

I've been trying use `ParseExact()` to convert the date for me but I just can't seem to get it to work, I get this as an error;

> Cannot convert value "2019-09-10:12:40:03 " to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
$logfile =  "C:\logs\APP.log"
cat $logfile | Select-String "ERROR" -SimpleMatch | select -Expand line | foreach {
    $_ -match '(.+)ERROR(.+)'| Out-Null 

    $error_time = [DateTime]($matches[1])

    $culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
    $error_time = [DateTime]::ParseExact("$matches[1]", "yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss", $culture)
    if ($error_time -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60)) {
        Write-Host "CRITICAL: There is an error in the log file" $logfile "around "$error_time;
    } else {
        Write-Host "OK: There was no errors in the past 24h"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. `[DateTime]($matches[1])`:
   Your timestamp has a colon between the date and time portions. That is not among the formats that PowerShell could cast to a `DateTime` object.
2. If you take a closer look at the error message you'll notice that there's trailing whitespace after the timestamp. The pattern you're using in `ParseExact()` doesn't account for that. Also, putting `$matches[1]` in double quotes (`"$matches[1]"`) does not get you the value of the first capturing group as a string. What you're effectively getting is `"$matches" + "[1]"` because PowerShell does not support index- or dot-access with variables in strings.

Remove the double quotes and trim the value of the capturing group to remove the trailing whitespace.

```
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$error_time = [DateTime]::ParseExact($matches[1].Trim(), 'yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss', $culture)
```

Also, remove the line

```
$error_time = [DateTime]($matches[1])
```

Comment: This has worked perfectly, thank you for your help with this.